# Guarantee function call in logical AND expression

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

I am in the process of refactoring some code using C++ atomics. The code looks like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> someFlag{}; // This can be set to true using a public method

// ...

const bool cond1 { someFunction() };
const bool cond2 { otherFunction() };

if (someFlag.load())
{
    someFlage.store(false);

    if (cond1 && cond2)
    {
        performSomeAction();
    }
}
```

I'm currently planning to rewrite the `if` statement like this:

```
if (std::atomic_exchange(&someFlag, false) &&
    cond1 && cond2)
{
    performSomeAction();
}
```

What is extremely important, is that after this `if` statement, the `someFlag` variable is set to `false`.
I therefore want to make sure that the call to `atomic_exchange` always occurs, regardless of the value of `cond1` and `cond2`. Can I be guaranteed that this will be the case since boolean expressions are evaluated left to right, regardless of optimisation settings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the order is guaranteed. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> Every value computation and side effect of the first (left)
>   argument of the built-in logical AND operator `&&` and the built-in
>   logical OR operator `||` is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side effect of the second (right) argument.

Answer (score 7):

In `if (std::atomic_exchange(&someFlag, false) &&
    cond1 && cond2)`

- `std::atomic_exchange(&someFlag, false)` will be called first.
- If evaluate to `true`, evaluates `cond1`
- If `cond1` is true, evaluates `cond2`.
- and finally `performSomeAction()` if `cond2` is also `true`.